# How to resolve the "Object 'Note' not found error" when using rmst2 function from survRM2 package?

Tags: survival-analysis

I aim to compare the restricted mean survival time  between the two treatment groups in the Anderson dataset
[Anderson dataset](https://statweb.stanford.edu/%7Eolshen/hrp262spring01/spring01Assignments/anderson.txt)

Here is the structure of my data frame:

```
    'data.frame':   42 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ survt : num  19 17 13 11 10 10 9 7 6 6 ...
 $ status: num  0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 ...
 $ sex   : Factor w/ 2 levels "female","male": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ logwbc: 'labelled' num  2.05 2.16 2.88 2.6 2.7 2.96 2.8 4.43 3.2 2.31 ...
  ..- attr(*, "label")= Named chr "log WBC"
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "logwbc"
 $ rx    : Factor w/ 2 levels "New treatment",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..- attr(*, "label")= Named chr "Treatment"
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "rx"
 - attr(*, "codepage")= int 65001
```

I used the following code to compare the restricted mean survival time between the two treatment groups ("New treatment" vs. "Standard treatment):

```
time <- anderson$survt
status <- anderson$status
arm <- anderson$rx
rmst2(time, status, arm )
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in rmst2(time, status, arm) : object 'NOTE' not found
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In max(tt) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
2: In min(ss[tt == tt0max]) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
3: In max(tt) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
4: In min(ss[tt == tt1max]) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I converted the sex and rx variables from factor to numeric and the function worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue where my `arm` was a numeric, but did not begin at 0.  Ensuring the first arm was 0 and the other arm was 1 fixed this.